# React-Native Flatlist RenderItem doesn't render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I don't get any errors. I use flatlist in the home page of my code without any errors but it doesn't render in the second page. It also doesn't display console.log inside renderItem.

```
const NamazTakibi = () => {
    const [ayet, setAyet] = useState('');

    const fetchAyet = async () => {
        try {
            const ayet = await axios.get('https://api.acikkuran.com/surah/6/verse/1?author=14');
            setAyet(ayet)
        } catch {
            console.log("error");
        }
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        fetchAyet();
    }, []);

    
    const renderItem = ({item}) => {
        return (
            <Cards item={item} />
        )
    }

    return (
        <FlatList
            style={styles.container}
            data={ayet}
            renderItem={renderItem}
        />      
    )
        
};

export default NamazTakibi;
```

Comment: Initially the `ayet` state is a string, then after the GET request, it's an object. I'm fairly certain that the `FlatList` component needs an [array of data](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#required-data).

Comment: Working snack https://snack.expo.dev/wGlmxfaAj with your code